# Extracting data from two html attribute in imacros

Tags: javascript, imacros

I'm trying to extract text from this HTML tag using iMacro

```
<div class="labValu overHidden">
Ready to Move
(New Property)
, Freehold
</div>
```

I'm expecting this output

```
Ready to Move
(New Property)
, Freehold
```

This is what I have tried to achieve this

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=div ATTR=CLASS:labValu&&overHidden&&TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
```

And

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=div ATTR=CLASS:labValu overHidden&&TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
```

And

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=div ATTR=CLASS:labValu, overHidden&&TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
```

Also

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=div ATTR=CLASS:labValu+overHidden&&TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
```

But no success for any of these tries Does any one has any idea about this, any help will be much appreciated . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Oh finally got this thing done right just by using tag

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=div ATTR=CLASS:labValu<sp>overHidden&&TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
```

Hope this help to anyone looking for the same problem.